# how to splice radio button values in array

Tags: angular

Can someone please help, when i select radio button, then that value i am storing in array. but when i unselect the radio button it is not splicing from array.Please help what's wrong in my code and what i need to put.

> Html

```
<mat-radio-button (change)="addCorrespondingAuthor($event, author.authorId)" ></mat-radio-button>
```

> Ts

```
addCorrespondingAuthor(e, authorId) {
// alert(e.checked);
if (e.checked=authorId) {
// alert(authorId);
this.authorErr = "";
this.correspondingAuthors.push(authorId);
alert(this.correspondingAuthors);
} else {
let index = this.correspondingAuthors.indexOf(authorId);
this.correspondingAuthors.splice(index, 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Should your "if" be like: `if (e.checked == authorId) ...` ??

Comment: No i removed that space now. splice is not working.

Comment: What I meant is: you are doing an "assignment", instead of comparison in your `if()`.  If you do this, the flow will never go to else(unless the assignment is falsy)

Comment: Then what should i place. I need to call splice when i unselect.

Comment: radio button or checkbox??. Anyway is a bad idea store in an array, better make an array of [true,true,false,false,true..]. In submit create the array